# Sketch of $f$ defined as an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I posted a past exam question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317803/past-exam-question-on-integral-of-an-even-function). It now asks to draw a rough sketch of $f$, showing where it is positive and negative.
Do I draw a rough sketch of $e^{t^2}$?
I know the integral of this is going to be some kind of error function but that surely can't be the route to take. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we already know, that the function is even and bounded from below with $-\sqrt\pi/2$ at zero and its derivative changes sign at zero, the question of rough sketch is essentially the question of roots: $$f(x) = \int_{1}^{x^2} e^{t^2} \; dt = 0,$$ which implies, that $$F(x^2)-F(1)=0,$$ where $F(u)$ is the antiderivative of $e^{t^2}$. Now this means, that $F(x^2)=F(1)$. If $F(u)$ is continuous, the solutions of $x^2=1$ are the solutions of the initial equation.
P.S.: Consider upvoting my answer and marking as answer if it helped, please.

Comment: Continuity of a function $f$ is not enough to have that $f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$. Take, for example, $f=\sin$. This property is called injectivity, and continuity has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Botond, you're right, my mistake. It is enough, however, to show, that $F(u)$ is differentiable and always positive or negative (which both are quite obvious in this case), right?

Comment: For strict monotonicity, it's enough to have strict positivity or negativity of the derivative. If $F(t)$ is the antiderivative of $\exp(t^2)$, then we have that $F'(t)=2t\exp(t^2)$, which does not have a constant sign.

Comment: I'd go this way: $f$ is even, which means that if $x_0$ is a root of $f$, then so is $-x_0$. So we can restrict ourselves to $\mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\}$. It's clear that $x=1$ is a root. Now let $0 \leqslant u < 1$. Then by the MVT, we have that $\int_u^1 \exp(t^2) \mathrm{d}t=(1-u)  \exp(c^2)$ for some $c \in (u, 1)$ , which means that it does not have a root in $[0, 1)$. Similary, we can conclude that it does not have a root on $(1, v] \forall v > 1$.

Comment: But of course, you can do something like this: $F$ is continuous on $[0, a] \forall a > 0$, and differentiable on $(0, a)$ with $F' > 0$, so it's monotone increasing, which means that $x=1$ is the only positive root, and use the parity argument to show that $x=-1$ is the only negative root.

Comment: How is it bounded below by $-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$?

Comment: Well, in the answer to your previous question, that you've accepted, it is stated like this.